# Sum of two "np.longdouble"s yields big numerical error

Tags: python, numpy, long-double

Good morning,

I'm reading two numbers from a FITS file (representing the integer and floating point parts of a single number), converting them to long doubles (128 bit in my machine), and then summing them up.

The result is not as precise as I would expect from using 128-bit floats. Here is the code:

```
a_int = np.longdouble(read_header_key(fits_file, 'I'))
print "I %.25f" % a_int, type(a_int)
a_float = np.longdouble(read_header_key(fits_file, 'F'))
print "F %.25f" % a_float, a_float.dtype
a = a_int + a_float
print "TOT %.25f" % a, a.dtype
```

and here's the answer I get:

```
I 55197.0000000000000000000000000 <type 'numpy.float128'>
F 0.0007660185200000000195833 float128
TOT 55197.0007660185219720005989075 float128
```

The result departs from what I would expect(55197.0007660185200000000195833) after just 11 decimal digits (16 significant digits in total). I would expect a much better precision from 128bit floats. What am I doing wrong?

This result was reproduced on a Mac machine and on a Linux 32bit machine (in that case, the dtype was float96, but the values were exactly the same)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Matteo

Comment: My best guess is that your longdouble is "cast" to a regular python `float` (c-`double`) for the printing, but that's pretty difficult to prove :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your printing of the `np.longdouble`. When you format using `%f`, Python casts the result to a float (64-bits) before printing.

Here:

```
>>> a_int = np.longdouble(55197)
>>> a_float = np.longdouble(76601852) / 10**11
>>> b = a_int + a_float
>>> '%.25f' % b
'55197.0007660185219720005989075'
>>> '%.25f' % float(b)
'55197.0007660185219720005989075'
>>> b * 10**18
5.5197000766018519998e+22
```

Note that on my machine, I only get a bit more precision with `longdouble` compared with ordinary `double` (20 decimal places instead of 15). So, it may be worth seeing if the `Decimal` module might be more suited for your application. `Decimal` handles arbitrary-precision decimal floating-point numbers with no loss of precision.

Comment: Yep.  That's the conclusion I came to as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer and mgilson's are very similar, and I will surely try out the Decimal module.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the `%f` modifier constructs a float from your longdouble object and uses that when creating the format string.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.longdouble(55197)
55197.0
>>> a = np.longdouble(55197)
>>> b = np.longdouble(0.0007660185200000000195833)
>>> a
55197.0
>>> b
0.00076601852000000001958
>>> a + b
55197.00076601852
>>> type(a+b)
<type 'numpy.float128'>
>>> a + b == 55197.00076601852
False
```

As a side note, even `repr` doesn't print enough digets to reconstruct the object.  This is simply because you can't have a float literal which is sufficient to pass to your `longdouble`.

Comment: So, this means that the problem is in how the numbers are printed, but not on their actual value, am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @user1616528 -- That's what I'm saying -- Although I don't think that the above is hard proof of that.

Comment: Mh. but look at this:
> a + b - np.longdouble (55197.0007660185200000000195833)
-1.9717560917342780158e-12

Comment: @user1616528 -- Doubtful that will work.  the literal `55197.0007660185200000000195833` will get truncated to double precision by python (`55197.00076601852`).  In light of that, the answer that you're seeing is actually quite reasonable.

Comment: Just on a side note, I believe at this time even `np.longdouble("1.")` as a string goes via a double, which is arguably wrong. (actually it is a known bug)

Comment: @seberg -- Yeah, I experimented with that as well and came to the same conclusion.